# Power Charges - How long? How many?

Tags: path-of-exile

- How many seconds do the Power Charges last?
- How many Power Charges can you get?

What I already know:

- Power Charges reset their Duration upon gaining a new Power Charge.
- You can increase the number of PCs via Nodes in the Passive Skill Tree.

Here is additional information about the Power Charge: http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Power_charge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initially have up to three charges of each kind (power, frenzy, and endurance), which will last for 10 seconds - but as you've noticed, you can refresh this duration indefinitely.

This can be increased by an additional 3 charges and roughly 3.5-4 seconds (I'm not sure how those bonuses stack, but the difference is small enough) via passive skills.

Helping Alira in the Merciless Act 2 bandit quest provides another +1 max power charges.

Two-handed weapons can be corrupted to provide +1 max power charges.

The unique staff [Hegemony's Era](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Hegemony's_Era) can provide +1 maximum power charges, or +2 if corrupted with the right mod.

The unique wands [Void Battery](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Void_Battery) and [Storm Prison](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Storm_Prison) also provide + 1 maximum power charges, allowing for 2 more max charges if duel wielded.

The unique amulet [The Aylardex](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Aylardex) can provide +1 maximum power charges.

This leaves us with up to 10 max power charges, depending on gear chosen.

Comment: I just got the information that you can also get a PC from the Bandit Quest - Merciless,so I added that to your answer.